# socket io unir a la misma sala varios clientes

Tags: javascript, socket, socket.io

Estoy tratando de hacer un `Dashboard en tiempo real` pero la cada vez que `socket io` emite, solo este mismo los escucha.

Quiero que todos los conectados puedan emitir y escuchar, pero los `sid` los separan y no se escuchan entre ellos

**Cliente 1**

```
<script>
    var socket = io("http://localhost:3000/");

    setInterval(function(){
        socket.emit('client/random', {nfe:0,nbe:1,cpv:13,cmv:250.55});
    }, 2000);

    socket.on('server/random', function(num){
      console.log(num);
    });
</script>
```

**respuesta**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cliente 2**

```
<script>

var socket = io("http://localhost:3000/");    

setInterval(function(){
  socket.emit('client/random', Math.random());
}, 2000);

socket.on('server/random', function(num){
  console.log(num)
});
</script>
```

**Respuesta**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Servidor**

```
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('client/random', (num) => {
        socket.emit('server/random', num);
        console.log(num);
    });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running in http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: En la guia oficial de socket.io esta el ejemplo minimo de su uso https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Answer (score 0):

Para eso existe algo llamadas 'rooms', que traducido al español seria algo asi como habitaciones, estas permiten lo que requieres, aquí un ejemplo sencillo de lo que debes hacer para poder usarlas y para meter los usuarios que quieras a ella y que todos los que esten en esta puedan recibir estos datos:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('some room');
});
```

y para enviar un mensaje a la sala:

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

En las rooms puedes hacer tanto emit como broadcast, solo que cambian un poco su utilización, checa la documentación oficial de donde saque este ejemplo:

https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Espero sea de ayuda.